# How to display Bootstrap button label vertically using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to display bootstrap button label in following way-

S

U

B

M

I

T

Now I have following code-

```
<button name="form-submit" id="book-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

And this code displaying "SUBMIT".

How do I display each character of a button label vertically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give space after every letter: S U B M I T

add css too:

```
.btn-primary {
    float: left;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 15px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9kR9/)